# Registering on Webeassessor and not getting any option of SFDC

Tags: webassessor

I registered on Webassessor and I think I select some wrong optiob during registration and after successfully registration I am getting option of registration on google cloud. And i am not getting any option of certification of SFDC.

Kindly help me to get out of this as i have to register for Certification asap.

Comment: Seems like you have registered on a different webassessor site, [this](https://www.webassessor.com) is the correct site; kindly verify if you had used it

Comment: I register on the same site. I can login on the same link.I am redirecting to homepage saying "To register for the Professional Collaboration Engineer exam you must have a Google Cloud Webassessor account.  You can create a new account here. "

Comment: Could you update your question with a screenshot?